# Help with testing for convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Let $(a_k)$ denote a real sequence. Use the indicted test to show if $\sum a_k$ converges.

$\frac{(2k+1)(3k-1)}{(k+1)(k+2)^2}$ using Comparison Test of the limit form

$(-1)^{k-1}\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}$ using Alternating Series Test.

I am having trouble developing an intuition for these things. If people could help me with the intuition alongside actually solving these questions, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

For the first series notice that the numerator is degree $2$ and the denominator is degree $3$. You're looking for another series $b_k$ where $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_k}{b_k}$ exists, is finite and non-zero. You will need to match the degrees of the numerator and the denominator to get that, otherwise the limit will be either $0$ or $\infty$. $b_k = \frac{1}{k}$ does the trick.

For the second series I can't give you any intuition.. the hint about the alternating series test implies that it converges, and all you need to do is prove the conditions required to use it.